# IONIC AUDIO not working on android, says reference does not exist for the specified audio id

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**BRIEF EXPLANATION :** I have added a simple button in `**home.html**`. On clicking that button `playAudio()` function is called from `**home.ts**`.

> **It is working on browser, but on android it says** - `Unhandled Promise rejection: A reference does not exist for the specified audio id. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: null ; Value: A reference does not exist for the specified audio id.`

Below is my `home.ts` code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode';
import { NativeAudio } from '@ionic-native/native-audio';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public nativeAudio: NativeAudio , public backgroundMode : BackgroundMode) {

    //this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('audio1', './audio1.mp3').then((msg)=>{
      this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('audio1', 'https://okazari.github.io/Rythm.js/samples/rythmC.mp3').then((msg)=>{
      console.log("message: " + msg);
    }, (error)=>{
      console.log("error: " + error);
    });

  }

  public playAudio(){
    this.backgroundMode.enable();
    this.backgroundMode.on("activate").subscribe(()=>{
      this.nativeAudio.play("audio1");  
    });
    this.nativeAudio.play("audio1"),() => console.log('audio1 is done playing');
  }

}
```

> **:: How do i fix the problem ?**

Also attaching console screenshot of error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the exact reason but even i was stuck while loading an audio file from external url, this plugin works well for files that are packaged with the app.

Try using ionic [Media plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/) or  [Streaming Media plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/) instead and check if it works

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with mp3 files on IOS and ANDROID (and WEB/HTML5) by wrapping the preloadSimple and play methods in cordova ready, AND fixing a bug in the Josh Morony tutorial. He was passing the asset path to the play method, and should be passing the key instead.  Here is my solution:

https://github.com/dolthead/topzee/blob/master/src/app/services/audio.service.ts

I call the preload on each page where a sound is played, so it's very modular.

Comment: This works for me only on my browsers. It doesn't work for my phone. However, somehow it plays the sound only once when I start the app on my phone if I put the play sound in a do-while loop and not a while loop. Did you ever come across this issue?

Comment: No, I haven’t seen that problem. Take a look at the audio service in the topzee repo on GitHub, and see if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

So somehow I managed to get my app working by changing a little code in the service that Todd Hale provided. I don't check ifNative. Below is the code I am using. I have commented out what was originally there. Also, it should be noted that I have no idea what I am doing and yet somehow this worked.

```
play(key: string): boolean {
    const soundToPlay: Sound = this.sounds.find((sound) => sound.key === key);

    if (soundToPlay) {
        // if (this.isNative) {
        //     this.platform.ready()
        //         .then(() => this.nativeAudio.play(soundToPlay.key)
        //             .then((res) => console.log(res),
        //                 (err) => console.log('play error', JSON.stringify(soundToPlay), err))
        //         );
        // } else {
        //     this.audioPlayer.src = soundToPlay.asset;
        //     this.audioPlayer.play()
        //         .catch(() => {}); // ignore web player errors
        // }
        this.audioPlayer.src = soundToPlay.asset;
            this.audioPlayer.play()
                .catch(() => {}); // ignore web player errors
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to play the audio before it has been loaded in memory. You have to wait for the promise of preloadSimple to be fulfil before trying to play it. When the audio is done playing you can unload it from memory and load it again when needed. Here is a code sample:

```
this.nativeAudio.preload('audio1', 'audio1.mp3').then(() => {
    this.nativeAudio.play('audio1', () => this.nativeAudio.unload('audio1'));
});
```